# Can you use a custom string interpolation character in Scala?

Tags: string, scala, interpolation, string-interpolation

Scala's [string interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) is pretty straight forward to use:

```
val user = "Bob"
val message = s"Hello, $user"
//Hello, Bob
```

For string blocks containing lots of financial data, these normally need double escaping, however (which for large blocks, such as test data, might get long):

```
val user = "Mary"
val message = s"Balance owing for $user is $100"
//error: invalid string interpolation $1, expected: $$, $identifier or ${expression}
//error: unclosed string literal
val message = s"Balance owing for $user is $$100"
//Balance owing for Mary is $100
```

Is it possible to use a different interpolation character to avoid the double escape?

```
val characterA = "Randolph"
val characterB = "Mortimer"
val family = "Duke"
val film = "Trading Places"
val outcome = "wagered"
val message = at"Your property was @{outcome} for $1 by brothers @{characterA} and @{characterB} @{family}"
//Your property was wagered for $1 by brothers Randolph and Mortimer Duke
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a different interpolation character to avoid the double escape?

`$` is part of Scala [syntax](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html), however it is at least possible to define [custom string interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html#advanced-usage) along the lines

```
scala> implicit class DollarSignInterpolation(val sc: StringContext) {
     |   def usd(args: Any*): String =
     |     sc.s(args:_*).replace("USD", "$")
     | }
class DollarSignInterpolation

scala> val user = "Mary"
val user: String = Mary

scala> usd"""Balance owing for $user is USD100"""
val res0: String = Balance owing for Mary is $100
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Mario. Not quite what I was hoping for but, as you say, that's what's currently possible in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the [`format`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/StringOps.scala#L988) method:

```
val message = "Your property was %s for 1$ by brothers %s and %s %s"
println(message.format("actual outcome", "actual characterA", "actual characterB", "actual family"))
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks @Tomer. Unless I've got a need to format the substitutions in some way (e.g., decimal format) I tend to avoid it as it's less readable. But you're right, it's an option. In the block of text I was looking to substitute strings into (being a large block of json) it's just not ideal from a readability POV.